# MVC3 - Controller Method to Create Model Data and Associate with Guid from another Table / Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller-action

I have 2 Models, each having many properties - Object1 and Object2

I have foreign key relationship with them in SQL db - Object1 can have many Object2's

Upon creating Object2 in my Object2Controller's Create() Method, how would I associate Object2 with Object 1's Guid?

Here is code:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Object2 object2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            object2.Object2Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Object2.Add(object2);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View(object2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only see two options in this scenario:

1. Pre-fill the *Object1* GUID in the model, when you post it back from the view, just like the other properties.  This could be accomplished different ways depending on your requirements (user-selected drop-down, pre-populated into a hidden field, etc).
2. Keep track on the server of which *Object1* the current user is working on.  You might do this using the *Session* object, or even using *TempData*.

**Edit**

To create a new *Object2* from the *Object1* detail view, follow this flow.

First, a simple form on the detail view:

```
@using (var form = Html.BeginForm("Add", "Object2Controller", FormMethod.Get)) 
{ 
    <input type='hidden' name='Object1ID' value='@Model.Object1ID' />
    <submit type='submit' value='Add Object1' />
}
```

Then you'll have an *Add* method in the controller for *Object2* that pre-populates the foreign key:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add(Guid Object1ID)
{
    Object2 newObj = new Object2();
    newObj.Object1ID = Object1ID;
    return View("MyAddView", newObj);
}
```

This would point to the *Object2* detail form, which posts back to the *Create* method in your question.

Comment: Ideally on the detail view of Object1, I want an action button that the user can click to create Object2. So an association should be made from that. Possible that step 1 could accomplish part of this? Can you point me to any examples on the web or from your experience?

Comment: @HelloJonnyOh I added some details to my answer for that scenario, please check my update.

Comment: @MyAddView that would be your existing view used for adding a new *Object2* (in this case I'm assuming you are using the *Object2* model itself as the view model).

Comment: If my first view has @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Object1Id) and the link in my first view is generated using @Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", "Object1", new { area = "Area1" }) then how could I make the Object1Id available so the Create() method in my Object2 controller can access the Object1Id?